# The prisoner icons in Logistics

Tags: prison-architect

When I enter the Logistics view to assign prisoners to jobs, (see image) some of the icons that appear when I click on a work area are red, and sometimes they are white. I haven't been able to find anything online that can tell me what the color difference means. Does anyone already know what to do?

I can tell that it doesn't relate to the max jobs vs. qualified prisoners, because those numbers don't match.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

White icons are unfilled spots, meaning that a qualified worked could take that spot but is not yet assigned to the room. The orange/red icons are filled slots, meaning a qualified inmate is already assigned to that job in that room.

Comment: Oh, makes sense, that hadn't occurred to me. I always just assumed that inmates jumped at the chance, so to speak, and took whatever job was available. Thanks!

Comment: @TimS. you might also have inmates that are qualified for multiple jobs, if they pick one then the other places they qualify for will be left blank.

Comment: That just occurred to me after reading your answer -- it could explain why my workshop has been perpetually empty even with 2 qualified inmates. Thanks.

Comment: Is it just qualified inmates?  As far as I remember it's the number of job slots you have assigned rather than the number of qualified prisoners available.

Comment: You can assign inmates there until the cows come home, but if nobody is qualified, they won't start working there.